# SQLite changing layout of list

Tags: android, sqlite

Im working on the notepad tutorial from the android website. I have created a database with 2 entries: name and address. When the application is run only the Name is displayed. I want to display both Name and address. I have edited my filldata method but it doesnt work. See my code below. Any suggestions?

```
private void fillData() {
    Cursor notesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
    startManagingCursor(notesCursor);

    // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (TITLE + BODY)
    String[] from = new String[]{NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE,NotesDbAdapter.KEY_BODY};

    // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just text1)
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1};

    // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
    SimpleCursorAdapter notes = 
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, notesCursor, from, to);
    setListAdapter(notes);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `R.layout.notes_row` file you should have two `TextViews` one for the title and one for the address and then you will write:

```
String[] from = new String[]{NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE,NotesDbAdapter.KEY_BODY};

    // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just text1)
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1, R.id.id_of_the_second_text};

    // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
    SimpleCursorAdapter notes = 
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, notesCursor, from, to);
    setListAdapter(notes);
```

**Edit:**
`R.layout.notes_row` could be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView android:id="@+id/text1" 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 
<TextView android:id="@+id/text2" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks. Im trying to create a second textview in my notes_row file and I keep on getting an error. My code is show below. Any ideas?`$  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView android:id="@+id/text1" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<TextView android:id="@+id/text2" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

Comment: @user876343 please see my edited answer. In a xml layout you must have only one root element and because of this you must wrap your two `TextView` with another element(I used a `LinearLayout` but there are other options). With my above code you will have a layout with two `TextView` with one on top of the other.

Comment: Thanks just worked that out there myself! Cheers for the help!